# How to enable SNMP on a Citrix NetScaler 10.1

Tags: snmp, citrix, netscaler

I am trying to set up MRTG against a Citrix NetScaler 10.1 appliance, but I am not getting a response to SNMP requests.

I have added the MRTG machine as a SNMP manager and added a community.

It does not seem like there is very good documentation of how to set up SNMP with NetScaler, so I am at a loss.

The NetScaler has 3 interfaces, two on the inside, both in the same network, and one on the outside.

The management server is on a different VLAN, with a router between it and the NetScaler.

What steps must I take to get SNMP working with netscaler?

Updates:
snmpwalk reports a timeout on all 3 IPs of the VPX.
using show snmp stats in the terminal, "unknown community" increases when I run snmpwalk against the management IP of the VPX.

The community isn't unknown, though.. I have added it to the communities in the VPX's configuration.

Comment: ALL should mean GET, GET_BULK and GET_NEXT. SET is not supported by default : http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX122436
Though seems can be enabled with nsapimgr command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of back and forth, it turns out that you must create the community with permission "ALL". A bit questionable with regards to security, however.